# Android Room onDelete cascade not working properly

Tags: android, android-room, sql-delete

So I have this database with a Deck table, a Card table and a DeckCard table because there is a relation between these two that is a multi to multi ...when I try to delete a deck I delete the DeckCard row where the id matches and I've set the foreign key onDelete = CASCADE but it doesn't delete the deck any suggestion?
This is the repository for my n to n distinction

```
public class DeckCardRepository {
    private DeckWithCardsDao mDeckWithCardsDao;
     public void delete(Deck deck){
        DecksDatabase.databaseWriteExecutor.execute(() -> 
         mDeckWithCardsDao.delete(deck.getId()));
    }

}
```

Deck class

```
@Entity(tableName = "decks")
public class Deck implements Serializable {
    @PrimaryKey
    private long id;
    private String keyforgeId;
    private String name;
    @TypeConverters({ExpansionTypeConverter.class})
    private Expansion expansion;
    private int creatureCount;
    private int actionCount;
    private int artifactCount;
    private int upgradeCount;
    private int sasRating;
    private int powerLevel;
    private int chains;
    private int wins;
    private int losses;
    private int totalPower;
    private int totalArmor;
    private int localWins;
    private int localLosses;
}
```

Card class

```
Entity(tableName = "cards")
public class Card implements Serializable {
    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    private String id;
    private String card_title;
    private String card_type;
    @TypeConverters({HouseArrayTypeConverter.class})
    private House house;
    private String card_text;
    private int amber;
    private String front_image;
}
```

Card deck class

```
Entity(tableName = "cards_deck_join",
        primaryKeys = {"cardId", "deckId"},
        foreignKeys = {
                @ForeignKey(
                        entity = Card.class,
                        parentColumns = "id",
                        childColumns = "cardId"),
                @ForeignKey(onDelete = CASCADE,
                        entity = Deck.class,
                        parentColumns = "id",
                        childColumns = "deckId"),
        })
public class CardsDeckRef {
    @NonNull
    private String cardId;
    private long deckId;
    private int count;

    public CardsDeckRef(String cardId, long deckId, int count) {
        this.cardId = cardId;
        this.deckId = deckId;
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

MyDao

```
@Dao
public interface DeckWithCardsDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    void add(CardsDeckRef cardsDeckRef);

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM cards INNER JOIN cards_deck_join" +
            " ON cards.id=cards_deck_join.cardId WHERE cards_deck_join.deckId =:deckId")
    LiveData<List<Card>> getCardsForDeck(final long deckId);

    @Query("DELETE FROM cards_deck_join WHERE cards_deck_join.deckId=:deckId ")
    void delete(final long deckId);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ON CASCADE DELETE` (i.e. what `onDelete = CASCADE` adds to the table) will delete children if the parent is deleted. It won't delete the parent if a child or even if all children are deleted.

Rather to delete a deck and all the cards_deck_join rows associated with the deck you should use

```
@Query("DELETE FROM decks WHERE id=:deckId ")
void delete(final long deckId);
```

the deletion of the deck will then be cascaded down to the cards_deck_join table.

---

If you wanted to automatically delete a deck if after deleting from  cards_deck_join there were no children then you could use a **TRIGGER** e.g.

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS delete_empty_deck 
    AFTER DELETE ON card_deck_join
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM decks 
            WHERE (SELECT count(*) FROM card_deck_join WHERE deckid = old.deckid) = 0 AND decks.id = old.deckid;
    END;
```

- As room doesn't support the generation of Triggers (as far as I am aware, with the exception of FTS when it does generate some Triggers), you would have to add the TRIGGER outside of room (e.g. via a callBack that overrides onCreate or OnOpen).